# A weird mistake in determining range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider $f(x) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 3}$. Now we can find range of $f(x)$ using the function's derivative, but another way is this: We add and subtract  $3$ . So $f(x) = x^2 + 3 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 3} - 3 = a + \frac{1}{a} - 3$ where $a = x^2 + 3 \gt0 $ and also we know if $a\gt 0 $ then $a+ \frac{1}{a}\ge2$ so the result is that range of $f(x)$ is $[-1 , +\infty)$ but it is wrong and the right range is $[\frac{1}{3},+\infty)$. This method can used for many functions and it's right but I don't know why it is wrong here. If someone could explain when we can/cannot use it , my problem will solve .

Comment: In fact $a = x^2 + 3 \ge 3$, not merely positive.

Comment: What does "using derivation" mean? "Derivation" isn't a technique, it's a noun that means roughly "the way to find the answer, written down and explained." Every problem that has a solution has a derivation.

Comment: @StellaBiderman. I edited. Generally, this is conceptually a GREAT problem in my view...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $a$ is not just greater than $0$, it is in fact greater than $3$. This means that, while $a + \frac1a \geq 2$ is *true*, that does not mean that it's also possible that $a + 1/a = 2$. In fact, $a + \frac1a \geq \frac{10}{3}$, and this bound is tight, in the sense that for the right value of $x$ we also have $a + \frac1a = \frac{10}{3}$.

Comment: Can you say how did you get $a + \frac1a \geq \frac{10}{3}$ ?

Comment: We have $a \geq 3$. For $a = 3$, $a + \frac1a = \frac{10}{3}$. As $a$ increases (from 3), the number $a + \frac1a$ also rises (you could see this by drawing the graph and looking at it, or formally by computing the derivative of $a + \frac1a$ and seeing that it is positive for $a \geq 3$).

Comment: Therefore in similar questions if $a\gt a_0$ where $a_0\gt 0 $ we can't say $a + \frac{1}{a} \ge 2$ and we must determine $a + \frac{1}{a}$ . Is that right ?

Comment: Sure. But note for instance that if $a_0 = \frac12$, then $a_0 + \frac1{a_0} = \frac52$, but that does not mean that $a +\frac1a \geq \frac52$, because $a + \frac1a = 2$ is still possible (for $a = 1$). The difference is that the function $x + \frac1x$ decreases on the interval $(0,1]$.

Comment: So in that case we can say $2 \leq a +\frac1a \leq \frac52$ . Is this right ?

Comment: @S.H.W. You *absolutely can* say $\forall a.\ a + \frac 1a \ge 2$. What you can't say in this case is $\exists x.\ a + \frac 1a \le 2$. The closest you can get is $\exists x.\ a + \frac 1a \le \frac{10}3$ (and then you must show $\forall x.\ a + \frac 1a \ge \frac{10}3$ to be sure you've got the bounds right).